# Microsoft Visual Basic and Adobe Photoshop trouble

Tags: adobe-photoshop, visual-basic

I have recently learnt to use Microsoft Visual Basic. However, I closed (by clicking  the "X") on the box where the forms could be edited, by mistake. I cannot bring it back. How do I bring it back?

Below is a snip of what I am trying to ask about. The *Form Layout* and *Project* boxes are there, but not the one where the forms are edited.

[image]

I have the same problem with Photoshop. The *Layer* box is not there. How do I bring it back?

[image]

Comment: Double click `Form1 (Form1)`. Failing that, look in the Window or View menu.

Comment: Yes that has worked alright! Now can you please tell me how to get the *Layers* box for Photoshop?

Comment: Look in the Window menu.